# Smooth points in fibers of moment map

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, submanifold, moment-map

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group acting on a smooth manifold $X$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$. Consider the induced action on the cotangent space $T^*X$ which is always Hamiltonian with (G-equivariant) moment map denoted by $\mu: T^*X \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^*$.

**Question:** Given $\lambda \in \mathfrak{g}^*$ a $G$-invariant point. We have: $\alpha \in \mu^{-1}(\lambda)$ is a smooth point if and only if the differential at $\alpha$, $d_\alpha\mu$ is surjective.

**What I have** I know, $$Ker(d_\alpha\mu) = T_\alpha ( G\dot\alpha)^{\perp \omega}$$ where $\perp \omega$ means the orthogonal complement with respect to the canonical symplectic form on $T^*M$ and $$Im(d_\alpha\mu)=Lie(G_{\alpha})^\perp$$, where $G_\alpha$ is the stablizier of $\alpha$ in $G$ and $Lie(G_{\alpha})^\perp=\{f \in Lie(G)^* : f(Lie(G_\alpha))=0\}$.

I think (for what I read) that this should be a quite standard result. Could anyone give me a hint or a reference for understanding how to prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by a smooth point?

Comment: I mean a point such that the dimension of the tangent space at that point is minimal (i.e. coincides with the dimension of the manifold). I have a more algebro geometric point of view in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an argument which holds tells us that for $f:M\to N$ a smooth map,if $\alpha\in f^{-1}(\lambda)$ where $d_\alpha f$ is surjective, $\alpha$ is a smooth point of $f^{-1}(\lambda)$.

If $d_{\alpha}\mu$ is surjective then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $\alpha$ where $d\mu$ is surjective (by lower semicontinuity of the rank), then $\mu\vert_{U}$ is a submersion. The implicit function theorem says that $\mu\vert_{U}^{-1}(\lambda)=U\cap \mu^{-1}(\lambda)$ is a submanifold of $T^*X$ and hence $\alpha$ is a smooth point of $\mu^{-1}(\lambda)$ by the following argument. Because $\mathcal{O}(\mu^{-1}(\lambda))_{\alpha}\cong\mathcal{O}(\mu\vert_{U}^{-1}(\lambda))_{\alpha}$ we see that the maximal ideals of these rings are isomorphic and hence if $\mathfrak{m}_{\alpha}$ and $\tilde{\mathfrak{m}}_{\alpha}$ are the maximal ideals of these stalks, then $\mathfrak{m}_{\alpha}/\mathfrak{m}_{\alpha}^2\cong \tilde{\mathfrak{m}}_{\alpha}/\tilde{\mathfrak{m}}_{\alpha}^2\cong \mathbb{R}^{\dim M-\dim N}$ as desired.

Here's some intuition behind the dimension given to the submanifold. Let $f: M\to N$ be a submersion ($d_xf$ is surjective for each $x\in M$). Let $V$ be a coordinate neighborhood of $f(x)=\lambda$ in $N$ and $U$ a coordinate neighborhood of $x$ which maps into $V$. We can represent $f$ as a function now $\mathbb{R}^{m}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and elements of $f^{-1}(\lambda)$ will be solutions of the set of equations \begin{align}
f^1(x^1,\cdots, x^m)&=\lambda^1\\
f^2(x^1,\cdots, x^m)&=\lambda^2\\
\vdots\quad&\\
f^n(x^1,\cdots,x^m)&=\lambda^n
\end{align}
So we can think of $f^{-1}(\lambda)$ as the intersection of $n$ hypersurfaces of codimension $1$, and in the tangent space of the intersection will be given by the intersection of $m$ codimension $1$ hyperplanes, yielding a dimension of $m-n$.

The reverse direction requires more time than I have right now, but I may be able to expand upon this later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to ask you about your last isomorphism: why do you find dim M - dim N? I would be very happy if you suggest me some reference for studying it. Thank you.

Comment: I added some discussion in the body of my answer. The differential geometry version of this story can be found in John Lee's book on smooth manifolds.

Comment: Thank you, I marked the answer as right. Clearly, if you will explain the reverse too, it would be great. Anyway, thank you again, very useful.

Comment: @wood I noticed you unaccepted my answer, was something I wrote not clear to you?

Comment: No, it is just that I hope for at least a sketch of the reverse direction. I thought you have not had time to add it, but if I accept your answer no one else is going to add a more complete answer. I'm sorry

Comment: I was thinking about this question and I think the reverse is in general false. In fact, without further hypotheses, we could have for example a Lie subgroup $H$ of $G$ acting trivially and in particular $d_{\alpha}\mu$ is never surjective. Could maybe be sufficient to require $G$ compact?